# Class design for an app that reads data from Active Directory

Tags: c#, design-patterns, active-directory, domain-driven-design, directoryservices

I am hoping someone can help me regarding design and architecture for an application.

The application is basically a service written in C#. The purpose of this service is mainly to read data from Active Directory and Save it to a local database (that data is later going to be used for reporting purpose but that's not in the scope of this application).

The attributes for an Active Directory object and my database fields doesn't always have one to one mapping. So for example, let's say I read 3 attributes of a User AD object and based on those 3 attributes I set a flag in database column (so here in this case it's 3-1 mapping between AD attribute and database field).

I am also going to collect the extended attributes from Active Directory (those attributes I am going to read from an XML file and I will pass it to Active Directory API query).

There could also be custom AD objects (not necessary AD object like User, Contacts, Groups etc. But they can be a completely new custom object that is not present in AD by default OR could be an extended object like a special user extending from standard User AD object). For reading AD attributes I am using System.DirectoryServices API of .Net.

Initially I was exploring Domain Driven Design to implement this application, but I don't have much business logic and there could be a lot of unknown entities (custom AD objects).

I was wondering what is the best way to design such an application?

Comment: Do you actually have *code*? If not this is likely a [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) question.

Comment: @EBrown It might be more on-topic at Programmers.SE, but it's also too broad to be well-received there.

Comment: @Ixrec That is probably true - the OP should probably be more specific and show some sort of effort before it would be well there as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should focus more on the problem you are trying to solve and less on what a `*DD` approach says is "best."  The reason for that is no *-driven-design approach is going to answer the questions you have for the level of detail you're now at.

At a broad level, you have the following:

- An active directory system
- A localized representation of the active directory system
- Active directory users
- Localized versions of those active directory users.

And you've told us that the localized version of the user depends upon the properties of the active directory user.

So that loosely tells me that you need two classes for the users and methods to interact with two systems.

You want two classes of users because they belong to separate systems.  And when those separate systems change, you want to decouple or minimize the effects of that change from the other user class.

So what does a rough class design look like?  You might get lucky and be able to inherit and extend [this base User class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provided by Microsoft for accessing Active Directory.

Your localized user class will need to be something of your own creation though, based upon what you know you need to store.

You'll also need to either a) add some interaction methods to the User classes or b) create a data-store class for the interaction.

```
public class MyADUserClass : UserPrincipal {}

public class MyLocalUser
{
    public MyLocalUser(MyADUserClass user)
    {
        //Do something here based upon user.Properties
    }
}

public class MySystemsHandler
{
    public List<MyADUserClass> FetchAllADUsers(...) {}
    public void CopyADUsertoLocal(List<MyADUserClass> ADUsers)
    {
        foreach(MyADUserClass aduser in ADUsers) 
        { 
            MyLocalUser luser = new MyLocalUser(aduser);
            ... //copy to local store here
        }
    }
}
```

You said: "I don't have much business logic and there could be a lot of unknown entities (custom AD objects)"  And to confirm your suspicions, domain driven design won't really tell you how to resolve the system design questions that you have.  DDD's focus is at a broader level than what your task needs to address.  As my example suggests - focus on the core classes first that you need for a solid design and continue building it from there.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I totally understand what you are suggesting. Now as your mentioned that User is one of the object in Active Directory out of many other AD objects (Groups, Computer, Printers etc). I can create local and AD representation of those objects in my system. But like I mentioned that in Active Directory, it is possible to create a complete new Object (let's say an object named AdvancedUser or Customer or anything).

Comment: Till now we have a system that reads the entire AD schema on Service startup, so I do have all those custom/extended Objects and their related attributes. But how you suggest to handle those custom Active Directory objects? I can't create Local and AD classes for them as they may vary from customer to customer and are unknown to me. Sorry for my bad English btw, I hope you understand what I am trying to exlain here :)